# IzPack: How to show UTF-8 license with LicensePanel?

Tags: izpack

As title. My license file contains UTF-8 characters and by default IzPack's LicensePanel seems to expect ASCII text files.

Is there a solution to this?

**UPDATE:**

I tried using "encoding" attributes with my resource line:

```
<res id="LicencePanel.licence" src="Licence.txt" encoding="utf-8"/>
```

It didn't work.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this issue?  I need to display a license in multiple different locales including Japanese, Russian and Korean but am hitting the same issue.  Specifying the encoding doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar problem with my LicencePanel.licence resource. I have an InfoPanel.Info resource in my installation as well. Both my info file (readme.txt) and licence (licence.txt) are in plain text format. My compiler accepts the readme file, but not the licence file when I run the installation.

Perhaps it isn't an encoding problem, since both files were in the same format, but the info file was accepted and the license was not.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this isn't going to work.  I looked at the source for 4.3.5 and it looks like this may be a bug.  Maybe it is fixed in a future version.  I had a look at the source and this is the issue.  Inside LicencePanel.java:

```
        String resNamePrifix = "LicencePanel.licence";
        licence = ResourceManager.getInstance().getTextResource(resNamePrifix);
```

ResourceManager has two methods:

- `public String getTextResource(String resource, String encoding) throws ResourceNotFoundException, IOException`
- `public String getTextResource(String resource) throws ResourceNotFoundException, IOException`

The first second one is being used while the first one should be used.

*Edit*: Just checked 5.0.0-rc1 and I think the issue occurs there too.  (Didn't test just glanced at the code).